# Change CSS during an animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have some buttons with their CSS style.
When an animation starts I would like to change their style for the duration of the animation.

Stuff like changing the color, changing the pointer, changing the hover; to make them look "disabled" basically.

I have a global var which is "true" while the animations runs, and turns "false" when the animation is not running.

In order to achieve this goal, I have tried many things, but none of them worked, I tried:

- changing the name of the class based on the var value, and create two different CSS styles -> didn't work because it didn't get updated with the change of the var
- changing the style within REACT inside the function when the animation is called and changing it back when it's over. Using: `document.getElementById("firstOne").style =`

The second option it's the only one that actually worked well. The problem I can't edit back the hover to where it was before.

The question:

Is there a way to change the hover from React? Something like:
`document.getElementById("firstOne").style =`  ;

If not, is there a way to just tell it "from now just follow the style written on the CSS file"?. To kind of setting the style back to before.

If not, any other ideas on how to achieve my goal?

Thank you

Comment: Share relevant code so, others may be able to help you.

Comment: try saving the global variable in the state. This way whenever you update the value of this variable, component will re-render and the styles you apply to the buttons will also be changed

Comment: Thank you that worked!